# Model binding with Steven Sanderson's BeginCollectionItem doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, model-binding

I am trying to build a dynamic list of System.DateTime that binds to a model that contains other properties too. The simplified model looks like this:

```
public class MAbsence : ModelBase<MAbsence, Absence>
{

    public MAbsence ()
    {
        ExtraDates = new List<DateTime>();
    }

    ....

    [Display(Name = "Date extra")]
    public List<DateTime> ExtraDates { get; set; }
}
```

I am using a partial view to render the ExtraDates and it looks like this:

```
@model System.DateTime

@{
Random rand = new Random();
var Index = rand.Next();
 }
@using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("ExtraDates")){
<div class="ExtraDate" id="@Index">


<div class="form-group form-group-default " id="@Index">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)

    <input name="Date" id="Date_@Index" type="text" class="form-control value="@Model.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")"/>

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(M => M.Date, null, new { @class = "error" })
</div>

<a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>

</div>
}
```

And in the [HttpPost] Action I've tried to have as a parameter just the model and both the model and the IEnumerable ExtraDates, but none of them gets any value. They are both null.

```
[HttpPost]

    public ActionResult AbsenceAdd(MAbsence model, IEnumerable<DateTime> ExtraDates)
    {
      ... code that should process the list of dates and the MAbsence model. Both lists model.ExtraDates and ExtraDates are null.
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your creating your own html for the input, and adding `name="Date"` You need to use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new { @class="form-control" })`. And why do you have a parameter for `IEnumerable<DateTime> ExtraDates` when the model already has that property

Comment: And you have invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes) and your `LabelFor()` and `ValidationMessageFor()` make no sense and do not work - they need to be `@Html.LabelFor(m => m)` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)`

Comment: I am using this html as input because the     @Html.TextBoxFor doesn't work with the add/delete scripts.

Comment: Of course it does. But almost everything else in the code your have shown is wrong so I assume your scripts are too.

Comment: Ok, the web page looks and acts fine, except for the binding. I've said that I've tried to have as a parameter just the Model for the HttpPost Action, but it doesn't work either so I though I might try with this aditional parameter(IEnumerable<DateTime> ExtraDates). What I am doing wrong that stops the binding?

Comment: In order to bind correctly, the html your generating needs to be `<input ... name="ExtraDates[xxxx]" ... />` and a hidden input with `name=ExtraDates.Index" value="xxxx"` where `xxxx` is a `Guid`. Check what your currently generating. But `BeginCollectionItem` is designed for dynamically adding and deleting collections with complex objects. You just have a collection of value type (`DateTime`) and you don't really need the extra overhead of using that helper.